# Keyboard shortcut to minimize a window on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, minimize

How can I minimize a single window in Ubuntu?

I have looked in the keyboard shortcuts and there is a maximize windows but there isn't a minimize windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> Hide Window

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> Switch Windows Directly
[image]

[image]

Comment: Also: `Alt+Space->Enter` (as *Minimize* is first in the list). `Alt+Space` gets you a window menu from which you can select *Minimize Unmaximize Move Resize* and a slew of other choices.